Density of a subset of Schwartz space in the fractional Sobolev space
It is known that the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is dense in the fractional Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$ ($0<s<1$), as $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and  $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is dense in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
Recently, I saw a statement saying that the following subset of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$:
$$ \mathcal{A} := \left\{ f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N) : \mathcal{F}(f) \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{ 0\}) \right\} $$
is dense in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is the Fourier transformation of $f$.
Observe that, $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ does not contained in $\mathcal{A}$. Because of this observation, the density won't follow using the density of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
I would be thankful if anyone could help me get this density result. Similar comment for $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ will be very helpful.

Let $\chi_n\colon \mathbb R^d\to [0,1]$ be a smooth function with with $\chi_n(\xi)=1$ for $1/n\le |\xi| \le n$ and $\chi_n(\xi)=0$ for $|\xi|\le 1/2n$ or $|\xi|\ge 2n$. Recall that $||f||_{H^s(\mathbb R^d)} = ||\langle \xi\rangle^s\hat f||_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}$, where $\langle \xi\rangle=(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}$. By dominated convergence,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} |(\chi_n(\xi)-1)\hat f(\xi)|^2 \langle \xi\rangle^{2s} d\xi \to 0,\quad n\to \infty,\qquad f\in H^s(\mathbb R^d),
$$
which means that $f_n=\mathcal F^{-1}(\chi_n\mathcal Ff)\to f$ in $H^s(\mathbb R^d)$. Assuming that $f$ is Schwartz, also $\hat f_n$ is a Schwartz, compactly supported and $0\notin \mathrm{supp}(\hat f_n)$, which is to say that $f_n\in \mathcal A$. A general function in $H^s(\mathbb R^d)$ is first approximated by a Schwartz function, which itself is approximated by something in $\mathcal A$ by virtue of the preceding construction.

Thank you so much Sir, for the answer. Is this result true for the fractional Sobolev space W^{s,p}(R^N)? In this space, we generally do not have the representation of the norm in terms of Fourier transformation.
